# how to cite a report and working paper?

Tags: bibtex, citing

I'm facing following errors. I want to cite a certain report in my paper, but it is not working.

1. There were undefined references.
2. Citation 'jeff2000' undefined.

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{apacite} 
\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\begin{document} 
\cite{Jeff2000}
\bibliography{RefEAINew} 
\end{document}
```

`RefEAINew.bib` contains

```
@report{Jeff2000,
author = {Jeff Borland, and Peter Dawkins, and David Johnson, and Ross Williams},
title = {Returns to Investment in Higher Education},
institution = {University of Melbourne},
year = {2000},
}
```

Comment: Don't forget, if your file is called `mydoc.tex`, to run `latex mydoc; bibtex mydoc; latex mydoc; latex mydoc`. And to have a `\bibliographystyle{...}` **before** the `\bibliography{...}`.

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem, but the bib entry you posted has errors that should have gotten error messages about when running `bibtex`. The format should be NAME and NAME and NAME etc. without commas.

Comment: Thanks but problem still persist in my PDF format as it shows (?,?) instead of citation.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 9):

Removing the erroneous commas between the names of the authors, the document compiles:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{apacite} 
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@report{Jeff2000,
author = {Jeff Borland and Peter Dawkins and David Johnson and Ross Williams},
title = {Returns to Investment in Higher Education},
institution = {University of Melbourne},
year = {2000}}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document} 
\cite{Jeff2000}
\bibliography{\jobname} 
\end{document}
```

[image]